# Forex trading platform with backtesting for non-Windows?

Tags: linux, osx, finance

There is Metatrader platform, but it's for Windows only.

I'm aware that I could emulate MT4/5 under Wine and I've tried many times, but it simply doesn't work as normal (most of the time it crashes or GUI doesn't work properly ending up with bug reports to wine which aren't been solved).

I know there plenty of on-line services, however I'm asking for the software available for Mac or Linux.

Preferences:

- backtesting,
- supporting programming languages,
- open source,

but any software is appreciated.

Comment: Same as you - I do not know of any, however I can think of two options: Get a windows VPS (those are pretty cheap) or get to run a windows virtual machine on your mac/pc.

Comment: So far I'm using emulated MT4, it works (with the recent wine), but sometimes you can find some [bugs](https://bugs.winehq.org/show_bug.cgi?id=38595). AWS instances does the job as well. However some open-source alternative would be beneficial.